# AtomicLongMap read thread safety

Tags: java, synchronization, thread-safety

I have a following class:

```
public class Storage {
    protected static final AtomicLongMap<String> MAP;
    protected Storage () {
                MAP= AtomicLongMap.create();
    }

    public void decrement(String id) {
        long num = MAP.get(id);
        if (num  != 0) {
            MAP.decrementAndGet(id);
        }
    }

    public void putIntoActiveAgents(String id, Integer num) {
        MAP.put(id, num);
    }

    public void remove(String id) {
        MAP.remove(id);
    }

    public Long get(String id) {
        return MAP.get(ID);
    }
}
```

In my case I have let say 6 threads which are performing similar things:
Each thread checks if long in the map is equal to 1, if not, they call decrement, if yes, they call remove. 
Everywhere I read that AtomicLongMap is thread safe. I'm sure it is, when somebody is incrementing / decrementing long number, but I'm not sure if it is still thread safe when other thread are reading values from that map. My scenario:
1. Thread A reads value from the map - it's 2 (so it decrements the value)
2. Thread B reads the value before the counter has been decremented - it's still returning 2, so it also decrements value.
3. In result, nobody sees the value set to 1.

My question is in such case, do I need to make MAP synchronized?

Comment: You don't make a field, or an object, synchronized. You make methods, or blocks of code, synchronized. Your decrement() method is not thread-safe (i.e. not atomic), and your scenario where threads are checking the value, and then either decrement or remove, is not thread-safe either. You should first try to encapsulate that into a method. And then make that method thread-safe.

Comment: Are you looking for `ConcurrentHashMultiset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, looking at your code I suggest you use the ConcurrentHashMap. The Map interface in Java 8 has been updated with new functions such as computeIfPresent(). So your function "decrement(String id)" would look like this -

```
public class Storage {
    protected static final Map<String, Long> MAP = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void decrement(String id) {
        MAP.computeIfPresent(id, (id, currentValue) -> --currentValue);
    }

    public void putIntoActiveAgents(String id, Integer num) {
        MAP.put(id, num);
    }

    public void remove(String id) {
        MAP.remove(id);
    }

    public Long get(String id) {
        return MAP.get(ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, I'm not using Java 8, but I think that with even this approach, my porblem would exists

Comment: Infact your use case is the perfect example for computeIfpresent(). ConcurrentHashMap ensures that all the operations that are conducted within the lambda that you provide are atomic. Given a key, the map allows you to perform certain actions on the value is its present. You can decrement the value or even remove the mapping by returning null.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the source you'll see the that `com.google.common.util.concurrent.AtomicLongMap` (I assume you're refering to that class) internally uses a `ConcurrentHashMap<K, AtomicLong>` so reading does depend on the properties of `ConcurrentHashMap` whose JavaDoc states:

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently *completed* update operations holding upon their onset.

However, since you're circumventing the map here (you're reading, checking and then decrementing) your code is not thread-safe. Thus you might have to synchronize your methods or use a mechanism (you could try something like `AtomicLong#compareAndSet` but `AtomicLongMap` doesn't seem to provide access to that).

Comment: Hmm I read docs for AtomicLongMap to check the thread safetyness of the get method, but I couldn't find anything, I didn't check the ConcurrentHashMap docs, which makes everything obvious. Basically What I need to do, is to synchronize access to the Map.

Comment: @loicram yes you'll probably have to synchronize access to the map but with some refactoring you could try and synchronize on an entry only, i.e. if the value never changes but is a wrapper object that contains the counter you decrement, you could synchronize on that value only and thus if two threads operate on different keys they'd not block. Adding a new value might require some special care in that case although you could use some double-checked locking in that case.